# How do I remove an iframe from within itself (that has been dynamically created and loaded with src)

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to remove an iframe from within itself. The iframe is created dynamically and the content is loaded with 'src'.

I create my iframe like this:

```
    var i = document.createElement('iframe');
    i.id = 'proxy_frame';
    i.name = 'proxy_frame';
    i.setAttribute('src', url);
    document.body.appendChild(i);
```

Then from within 'url' I want to be able to remove/close the iframe.

Before loading the data into the iframe with src I used document.write:

```
    window.frames['proxy_frame'].document.write(html);
```

and then I was abloe to remove the iframe with:

```
    window.parent.document.getElementById("proxy_frame").parentNode.removeChild(window.parent.document.getElementById("proxy_frame"));
```

But this does not work with 'src'.

Note: This is for a bookmarklet so I don't want to use jQuery or another library.

Comment: Is the url on the same domain?

Comment: Do you mean when you set the `src` property it no longer is able to be deleted? That sounds like you may be hitting Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Url is not on the same domain. So of course its same origin policy, which does not happen if I load the content with document.write(). Thanks. I wonder if I can solve this some other way though.

Comment: And since I do not want to use any libraries json-p really isnt an option.

Answer (score 3):

Define a method in your parent page

```
function removeElement() {
  var d = document.getElementById('body'); // or any other parent element
  var proxy_frame = document.getElementById('proxy_frame');
  d.removeChild(proxy_frame);
}
```

To call this method from your iframe simply use this

```
<a href="#" onclick="top.window.removeElement();">Remove me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but "Error: Permission denied to access property 'removeElement'" because of same origin policy discussed above.

Answer (score 2):

For local domain `iframes` you don't need to rely on ids.

`window.parent.document.body.removeChild(window.frameElement);`

`window.frameElement` has reasonable support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the parent page as long as it's in a different domain.

Set up a page in your site that can be used to remove the iframe, then in the iframe you just go to that page.