# How to close an iframe within iframe itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How do I use javascript or jQuery to close an iframe within iframe itself? I've tried `<a href="javascript:self.close()">` but it didn't work.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on ids try my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086986/how-do-i-remove-an-iframe-from-within-itself-that-has-been-dynamically-created

Answer (score 90, accepted):

"Closing" the current iFrame is not possible but you can tell the parent to manipulate the dom and make it invisible.

In IFrame:

```
parent.closeIFrame();
```

In parent:

```
function closeIFrame(){
     $('#youriframeid').remove();
}
```

Comment: @citizen, if I don't have control to the parent domain. Can this be handled in iframe itself? Like in iframe, referencing the iframe itself by parent.getElementByID("iFrameID").remove();

Comment: oh it's cross domain? you won't be able to manipulate the dom without entering a whole new world of pain.

Comment: parent object is quite efficient.. I think this is how an iframe relates its parental page?

Comment: @citizenconn Do we have to set "x-frame-options" if the IFRAME is cross domain?

Comment: For what it's worth I was able to close an iframe with: document.getElementById("iframeID").remove();

Comment: To clarify @Bird's comment: this answer uses jQuery, which isn't really necessary (just for `$('')`).

Comment: is it also possible if the iframe is accessed by some other mobile apps ?

Answer (score 17):

```
function closeWin()   // Tested Code
{
var someIframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe_callback');
someIframe.parentNode.removeChild(someIframe));
}


<input class="question" name="Close" type="button" value="Close" onClick="closeWin()" tabindex="10" />
```

Comment: This does indead work! Implemented it in a few seconds. I recommend it!

Comment: Years late, I know, but I just want to point out that you're needlessly calling getElementById twice.  The second line of `closeWin()` should just be `someIframe.parentNode.removeChild(someIframe);`.

Comment: Thats amazing, but indeed, you can remove the second get element.

Answer (score 9):

Use this to remove iframe from parent within iframe itself

```
frameElement.parentNode.removeChild(frameElement)
```

It works with same origin only(not allowed with cross origin)

Answer (score 6):

None of this solution worked for me since I'm in a cross-domain scenario creating a bookmarklet like Pinterest's Pin It.

I've found a bookmarklet template on GitHub https://gist.github.com/kn0ll/1020251 that solved the problem of closing the Iframe sending the command from within it.

Since I can't access any element from parent window within the IFrame, this communication can only be made posting events between the two windows using window.postMessage

All these steps are on the GitHub link:

1- You have to inject a JS file on the parent page.

2- In this file injected on the parent, add a window event listner

```
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
       var someIframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframeid');
       someIframe.parentNode.removeChild(window.parent.document.getElementById('iframeid'));
    });
```

This listener will handle the close and any other event you wish

3- Inside the Iframe page you send the close command via postMessage:

```
   $(this).trigger('post-message', [{
                    event: 'unload-bookmarklet'
                }]);
```

Follow the template on https://gist.github.com/kn0ll/1020251 and you'll be fine!

Hope it helps,

Comment: The 2nd line of your even listener function (step 2) needlessly calls getElementById a second time with the same argument as before.  This line should instead just be:  `someIframe.parentNode.removeChild(someIframe);`

Comment: Also, I think there's a mistake in your code.  If the event listener is injected into, and running in the context of, the parent window, then you shouldn't write `window.parent.document.getElementById(...)` but rather just `document.getElementById(...)`, because it's already *in* the parent window.

Answer (score 1):

its kind of hacky but it works well-ish

```
 function close_frame(){
    if(!window.should_close){
        window.should_close=1;
    }else if(window.should_close==1){
        location.reload();
        //or iframe hide or whatever
    }
 }

 <iframe src="iframe_index.php" onload="close_frame()"></iframe>
```

then inside the frame

```
$('#close_modal_main').click(function(){
        window.location = 'iframe_index.php?close=1';
});
```

and if you want to get fancy through a

```
if(isset($_GET['close'])){
  die;
}
```

at the top of your frame page to make that reload unnoticeable

so basically the first time the frame loads it doesnt hide itself but the next time it loads itll call the onload function and the parent will have a the window var causing the frame to close

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the above solutions don't work if the domains of parent/child applications are different. Instead, you can use window.postMessage API if you own both applications.

Here is a simple example in React.

In Main Application

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("message", (event) => { 
    if (event.data === "closeWindow") {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  });
}, []);
```

In iframe Application

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    window.parent.postMessage("closeWindow", "*");
  }}
>
  close
</Button>
```

In this example, I demonstrated child-to-parent communication, but the API supports both directions.