# How do I remove iframe within itself by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, iframe, xhtml

I know that there are several similar questions, but I have to ask the question again with attached code because of being unable to work out.
I have two .xhtml file in JSF project. One is mainPage.xhtml has a button that generates dynamic html code to create an iframe (iFramePage.xhtml) and show it on the browser;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        /** Create dynamic iframe HTML code for iFramePage.xhtml **/
        function createIFrameHTML(){
            document.getElementById("iFrameContainer").innerHTML =  '<div id="iframe0"><iframe src="iFramePage.xhtml" width="450px" height="300px"></iframe></div>';
        }

        /** Close iFrame **/
        function removeElement() {

        /*Both lines work properly when I call inside this page, */
        /*..however it does not work by calling from iFramePage.xhtml */                

        //document.getElementById("iFrameContainer").removeChild("iframe0");
        $('iframe0').remove();
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="mainForm">

            <!-- Control Menu -->
            <div id="cntrMenu">
                <h:commandButton id="cntrBtn1" 
                    onclick="createIFrameHTML();return false;"></h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton id="cntrBtn2" 
                    onclick="removeElement();return false;"></h:commandButton>  
            </div>

            <div id="iFrameContainer">
                <!-- an iframe will be generated by createIFrameHTML() -->
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

The other page is iFramePage.xhtml that has some html and javascript code;

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript name="......js" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="....css" />
    <script>

        /** Close iFrame.**/
        function closeSelf() {
            /* Two lines works properly, however third line does not work!*/
            //window.top.location.href = "HIDDEN"; 
            //parent.document.location.href = "HIDDEN";
            parent.removeElement();

        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<body>  
    <input jsfc="h:commandButton" id="exitBtn" value="Kapat" onclick="closeSelf();" />
</body>
</html>
```

I can generate the iframe by clicking "cntrBtn1" button and removing by clicking "cntrBtn2" inside mainPage.xhtml. However, I need to remove the iframe within itself (iFramePage.xhtml). When I click "exitBtn" in iFramePage.xhtml, the iframe does not disappear. There is nothing about cross-domain, because mainPage.xhtml and iFramePage.xhtml are in the same JSF project, even in the same directory. I can redirect the parent page (looks at two lines in closeSelf() in iFramePage.xhtml), but I cannot remove the iframe by using parent element, why! Please, help me :)

Comment: The `parent` doesn't access `iframe` dom, but the parent window. You could perhaps try `parent.document.getElementById("iframe0").style.display='none'`. Or use parent child communication http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Comment: Instead of "parent.document.getElementById("iframe0").style.display='none'", "parent.document.getElementById("iFrameContainer").innerHTML = ' '" is more proper action, I think. Your advice gave me the inspiration, thank you. However, I could not succeed on applying window.postMessage mentioned in the link in your message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close an iframe within iframe itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754935/how-to-close-an-iframe-within-iframe-itself)

Answer (score 14):

Communicate between the parent and iframe using **[window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)**.

Replace the **closeSelf()** function in **iframe** page to the following :

```
function closeSelf() {
   parent.window.postMessage("removetheiframe", "*");
}
```

and on the parent page, add the following code to listen when the **iframe** sends a message :

```
function receiveMessage(event){
   if (event.data=="removetheiframe"){
      var element = document.getElementById('iframe-element');
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
   }
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

You can also check the origin of **postMessage** by **[event.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage#The_dispatched_event)** to make sure that the right **iframe** requested to remove the **iframe**.

Comment: I tried to apply your solution, but I could not work it properly. After your solution, mainPage.xhtml even does not generate the iframe, although "cntrBtn1" button is clicked.