# jQuery - Close iFrame Popup from within (close parent from within child)

Tags: jquery, iframe, popup, bpopup

I have an iframe in a popup window on my page using [bPopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) with the following setup:

HTML

```
<div id="iframePopup">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<button id="popIt">SHOW</button>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('#popIt').click(function(){
    jQuery('#iframePopup').bPopup({
        content:'iframe',
        contentContainer:'.content',
        loadUrl:'http://www.site-url.com',
        opacity:0.4,
        iframeAttr:('scrolling="yes"')
    });
});
```

This works fine but i need to be able to close the popup if i click a particular button in the iframe itself.

The bPopup docs/api state i can close the popup with:

```
jQuery('#close-btn').click(function(){
    var bPopup = jQuery('#iframePopup').bPopup();
    bPopup.close();
});
```

but this only works when the button is on the HTML page, not in the iframe. How can i target the `#iframePopup` from within the iframe?

Comment: Are you sure about this :jQuery(‘iframePopup’).bPopup(); . I think it should be jQuery(‘#iframePopup’).bPopup();

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I copied that snippet from there api docs which missed it out, now edited correctly as you said

Comment: This is related to iframes, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754935/how-to-close-an-iframe-within-iframe-itself  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881901/how-do-i-remove-iframe-within-itself-by-using-javascript