# Create and close iframe in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

I've written a bookmarklet (with a little help from the experts at Stackexchange) and I've run into a small little issue where I can't close the thing.

Here's the code (sensitive people should probably move on):

```
javascript: (function () {



var htmlheader = "<html><head></head>"

var html = htmlheader + "<body><a href='javascript:document.getElementById(\"TroubleiFrame\").style.visibility = \"hidden\"'>Close</a>" + 
                "</body></html>";

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
iframe.style.background = "#fff";
iframe.style.width = "50%";
iframe.style.height = "500px";
iframe.style.left = "25%";
iframe.style.top = "25vh";
iframe.style.position = "fixed";
iframe.style.zIndex = "9999";
iframe.id = "TroubleiFrame";
iframe.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0 100vw rgba(0,0,0,0.75)";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

})();
```

When clicking on the close link I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

If I paste the command in Chromes console it works:

> document.getElementById("TroubleiFrame").style.visibility = "hidden"

Do you have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? If possible I'd love a brief explanation too so I'm learning something from it.

/Patrik

Comment: Your close link is getting executed before ur iframe is appended to the body.Execute your top 2 statements after iframe is appended to the body.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could be? Running the bookmarklet brings up the iFrame with the link in it. Clicking the link gives me the error, not generating the frame?

Answer (score 1):

Your `iFrame` doesn't know about an element called "TroubleiFrame" since it is in a child window.

You need to call the parent instead, and from there you can close it

```
parent.document.getElementById("TroubleiFrame");
```

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754935/how-to-close-an-iframe-within-iframe-itself) to see how to close the iFrame properly. Right now you're just going to hide it

Comment: Yes, one step further! But I was unable to close the window though.

Got this error: 
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.sitename.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "data", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Comment: perhaps you should be creating the iframe first (about:blank) and set the content after it is created.

Answer (score -1):

I've also came across this problem creating a bookmarklet just like Pinterest's Pin It.

It should work cross-domain.

The only way I could work this out, was by posting events between the page inside the iframe and the parent page following this example on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/kn0ll/1020251

I've posted an answer on this other thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43030280/3958617

And also found one more example on this other thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21882581/3958617

Hope it helps!