# featherlight.js trigger close from the iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, featherlight.js

I use featherlight to open a image upload/resize/cropping page via an iFrame.

I would like to call the `closeTrigger` as soon as the user hits save (within the iFrame) so that they don't need to close it manually

I'm a bit confused about this. I've checked the `min.js` but couldn't find anything, and I also didn't find the Javascript action tied to the closing button...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer here
[How do I remove iframe within itself by using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881901/how-do-i-remove-iframe-within-itself-by-using-javascript)

iFrame (after eveything is done):

```
<script>parent.window.postMessage("closetheiframe", "*");</script>
```

ParentWindow:

```
<script>
function receiveMessage(event){
   if (event.data=="closetheiframe"){
  var current = $.featherlight.current();
 current.close();
   }
}
 window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

theoretically, if featherlight.current works fine, this would help me also on a page, where I use different iFrames to be opened and closed (not at the same time though)

Answer (score 3):

This also works: `parent.window.$.featherlight.current().close();`

Comment: great short approach, I like it... thank you and sorry for the missing feedback.. nevertheless I prefer to mark the other answer as accepted because it offers more flexibility to do some pre- or post processing on the parent frame...