# How to close Bookmarklet using iframe?

Tags: javascript

I have designed bookmarklet for my website. Thus the bookmarklet created using an iframe.  Iframe and  iframe  source are declared inside the script .

I have set the close button and the callback function are declared for my source page but it does not work.

Click the close button

Showing the below error.

> (DOMException:    Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8050"  from accessing a cross-origin frame. at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://localhost:8050/researcher_voice/iframe.html:19:172)).

Bookmarklet:

```
 <a class="article-bookmark" href="javascript: (function(){

        var iframeSrc = 'http://localhost:8050/researcher_20voice/iframe.html';
        var iframeStyle = 'position: fixed; z-index: 999999; width: 500px; height: 300px; left:300px; right: 0; top: 200px; border: none; overflow: hidden;                   background-color: black';
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', iframeSrc);
        iframe.setAttribute('id', 'kew-modal');
        iframe.setAttribute('style', iframeStyle);


        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.appendChild(iframe);


    }).call(this);">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Close-Button:

```
 function closeIframe() {
         var iframe = document.getElementById('id');
         iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    }
```

Comment: If the content is from same origin you could  - but you would need to use `document.getElementById('kew-modal')` and not ("id") - since it is likely NOT from the same origin you will not be allowed

Comment: And I have also use document.getElementById('kew-modal') but it repeated the same cross orgin error.

Comment: So the answer is no

Answer (score 0):

I've also came across this problem creating a bookmarklet just like Pinterest's Pin It.

The only way I could the cross-domain issue, was by posting events between the page inside the iframe and the parent page following this example on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/kn0ll/1020251

I've posted an answer on this other thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43030280/3958617

And also found one more example on this other thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21882581/3958617

Hope it helps!