# How to close a iframe inside itself?

Tags: javascript, iframe

So I have a iframe of `b.com` inside the website `a.com`
How can I remove the `b.com` iframe when I click on a button (or whatever) inside the `b.com` iframe.
I have full access to the source code on `a.com` and `b.com`

I need a JavaScript but non jQuery solution

I think this is the jQuery solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6754965/3630453

Comment: Are `a.com` and `b.com` programmers are friends ? becuase if they aren't - forget about it.

Comment: What do you mean "Close"? Remove the iframe from the parent? Clear it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754935/how-to-close-an-iframe-within-iframe-itself.

Comment: @user1929959 please read about cross domain policy

Comment: @user1929959 not that easy since it is cross domain

Comment: Sorry, when I say close, I mean remove.

Comment: @user3630453 can you answer the question i asked in comment ?

Comment: You have access to the source code on both pages. Both are friends...

Comment: @user3630453 well - read Quentin answer and also my additional comments

Comment: Ok, but with jquery it seems possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6754965/3630453 ?

Comment: @user3630453 jQ is not stronger than JS. the answer is no.

Comment: So I guess it is not easily possible? Ok thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't 'close' an iframe at all. The concept just doesn't exist.

You could link to a different (or blank) page.

You could remove the iframe from the DOM. Since the frame belongs to `a.com`, the JS that removes it **must** run on `a.com`. If you want to trigger it from `b.com` then you can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to send a message to `a.com` that asks it to remove the frame from the DOM. You will need to have code running on `a.com` to listen for the message and act on it.

You can use [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to stop a page from opening in a frame in the first place.

Comment: That's why i said : are both programmers (A's and B's) are friends... ( another solution is changining the Hash / postMessage like you said / cross domain iframe aka `top.frames[..]`)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: How is the relationship between 2 programmers relevant?

Comment: @Cerbrus a'com needs to support postMessage's message from b.com  - need to support scripts  . ( or hashchange event  - whatever)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: So, you're asking if the OP can modify both sites. Completely different question. But yes, it looks like he can.

Comment: @Cerbrus different question ? well maybe. (friends I mean , can exchange scripts)