# Bootstrap 3.3.1 modal popup close from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup, bootstrap-modal

I have an iframe through jQuery and bootstrap, and I need to add a **Close** button inside the iframe page itself, not from the popup window that opens.

I tried adding `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>` in the html popup page, but it does nothing.

Here is the current code with the outer `close` button, and an example page link of bbc.com:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.1/docs/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.1/docs/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Popup page</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding:0px">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="https://bbc.com"  style="width:500px; height:500px;  max-width:100%; max-height:100%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754935/how-to-close-an-iframe-within-iframe-itself) but not sure how to implement it in the current case.

Comment: your Close button seems to be working fine for me....

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I know, what I need to is to add the same button inside the page that is within the iframe.. not the one outside the page.  (the above is just an example with bbc.com, but if the popup link is within the server, I want to add the close button in it).

Answer (score 0):

you can just add button like this 
and provide some id 'blackout' to iframe.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.jQuery('#blackout').toggle('slow');">Open/Close</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tested it and it did nothing.