# How do I unset the "document.domain" property using JavaScript when I close my IFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, subdomain

I set the `document.domain` property at the top of my page, when I close my IFrame, I'd like to *"unset"* it.

How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: What language are you using, where is your code and what have you tried?

Comment: @LogicalBranch Thanks for the response.


I am using javascript. On Iframe load, I have set 
document.domain = 'XXX.net.in'.

on close, I want to remove document.domain

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what do you mean by "when I close my IFrame".
How do you close you IFrame?
Based on this answer [How to close an iframe within iframe itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754935/how-to-close-an-iframe-within-iframe-itself)
you can do something like this:

In IFrame:

```
parent.closeIFrame();
```

In parent:

```
function closeIFrame(){
     document.domain = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

But we can't set `document.domain = undefined`. If we set we are getting below error 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 'undefined' is not a suffix of the domain.